# Is this content duplicated? or or weak content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

firstly, my google webmaster tool said that i have 313 index. but if i search with site:, i only get 72 content.

from this [url](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/yVjVVbvxm_s), it said may because data not yet transfered from other server. ok its fine so i need to wait. but i also suspect content is duplicating in google perspective or may be weak content.

http://ratnadewi.net/indonesia/gallery/bali.makeup/balinese-makeup-and-wedding-i

http://ratnadewi.net/english/gallery/bali.makeup/balinese-makeup-and-wedding-i (its will be canonical to http://ratnadewi.net/gallery/bali.makeup/balinese-makeup-and-wedding-i)

what do you think? is it duplicated content? or its a weak content? its an image gallery. and i need translation for any content.

Answer (score 0):

The content is unique between the pages, meta tags, alt tags and body content. So it shouldn't be seen as duplicate content. I would just wait for Google to crawl more pages.